# How do I change the version of yarn used?

Tags: npm, homebrew, yarnpkg

I used Homebrew to install `yarn`. Running `yarn -v` shows that I currently use `0.23.2`. I ran `brew upgrade yarn` to get the latest version, which is `0.24.6`.

After Homebrew successfully upgrades `yarn`, I run `yarn -v` again, but the version is still `0.23.2`. How can I change the version of `yarn` that I am running?

Comment: what's ur terminal output of `which yarn`?

Comment: `/Users/DavidHu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.1/bin/yarn`

Comment: What is the output of this command: `ls -la /usr/local/bin/yarn``

Comment: you're hitting certain caching issues (`/Users/DavidHu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.1/bin/yarn` takes precedence over your `/usr/local/bin/yarn`). I would suggest you to go consistent with your package manager(for eg. OS level use `homebrew`, node packages use `npm` etc)

Comment: Hope this channel can help you https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1139

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I found an answer. It's not the prettiest, but since `yarn` always tell me what the most update-to-date version is, I can use npm to just install the latest version.

If the latest is 0.24.6

```
npm install --global yarn@.24.6
```

**EDIT:**

According to yarn's official documentation, the way to install/upgrade is:

```
brew install yarn

brew upgrade yarn
```

https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#mac-stable

Comment: Yarn's official stance on npm is "don't." Quote: "Note: Installation of Yarn via npm is generally not recommended. When installing Yarn with Node-based package managers, the package is not signed, and the only integrity check performed is a basic SHA1 hash, which is a security risk when installing system-wide apps.

For these reasons, it is highly recommended that you install Yarn through the installation method best suited to your operating system."

Comment: @jelder Does yarn provides any reasonable/straight-forward documented fix for this issue?

Comment: if you have denied with any write permission try this 'sudo npm install --global yarn@.24.6' it will ask your system password and enter

Answer (score 110):

```
yarn policies set-version <version number>
```

Per https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7146#issuecomment-477809216

Comment: This should be the correct answer but one thing to note, if you downgrade the yarn command `policies` may not be available in that version of yarn.

Comment: Is this method still correct?

    $ yarn policies set-version 1.19.1
    yarn run v1.3.2
    error Couldn't find a package.json file in "[deleted]"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: Worked for me downgraded to 1.16.0 from 1.21.1

Comment: In yarn 2 it’s `yarn set version <version number>` as per https://next.yarnpkg.com/cli/set/version

Comment: If you use this command and try to download a later version of node it'll revert back to the version you used in this command even if you remove `~/.yarn` and reinstall so beware of that

Comment: `Usage Error: Couldn't find a script named "policies".`

Comment: Usage Error: Couldn't find a script named "policies".

Answer (score 53):

You can use homebrew and yarn formula URLs to install older versions of yarn, then `brew switch` between yarn versions as needed. Works perfectly! Credit to github user robertmorgan.

> 1. First off, if you already have a version installed, unlink it from brew running the `brew unlink yarn` command in your terminal.
> 2. Next, in a web browser, find the [Pull Request that has been merged which contained the formula (version) of
>      Yarn](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr+is%3Amerged+yarn+)
>      that you want to install.
> 3. View the files changed in that Pull Request - there should be one for `Formula/yarn.rb`.
> 4. Click the "View" button for the `Formula/yarn.rb` file to see the whole contents of the file for that commit.
> 5. Click the button to view the "Raw" version of that file. This will open a url which should start with
>      `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/....`
>
>    This is the URL that you will need for the next step - so copy the complete URL to your clipboard.
> 6. Back in your terminal window, use the command brew install followed by the URL that you've copied.
>
>    e.g. to install v1.6.0 of yarn it would be:
>
>    ```
>    brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/fba7635ab69384ac980c635483a7af825bc06088/Formula/yarn.rb
>    ```
>
> You can then verify the versions available to Homebrew by running:
>   `brew list --versions yarn`, and switch between versions using `brew switch yarn VERSION_NUMBER`

Source: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1882#issuecomment-421372892

Comment: im not sure how things went but 2018, this should be marked as the correct answer :)

Comment: As of 2021, installation of yarn from a GitHub commit URL is unsupported. I instead had joy with `brew extract --version <version> yarn homebrew/cask` and `brew install yarn@<version>`

Comment: I tried to do this, `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DanBuild/homebrew-core/552359058976923c627d00e3dc99b40746618c7f/Formula/yarn.rb` 
and got this error: 
`Invalid usage: Installation of yarn from a GitHub commit URL is unsupported! brew extract yarn to a stable tap on GitHub instead. (UsageError)`

Comment: Christian has the correct answer - Here is what I did:

Comment: Christian has the correct answer - Here is what I did: `brew extract --version 1.6.0 yarn homebrew/cask` and then `brew install yarn@1.6.0`

Answer (score 32):

You can use

`yarn set version <version>`

For example, if you want the latest version, you can run

`yarn set version latest`

You can also set it to a specific number, for example,

`yarn set version 1.22.1`

You can view the full documentation at the [official website](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/set/version).

---

Note 1: A bug stops you from switching from yarn 2 to yarn 1. There are solutions to this in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/999).

Note 2: I don't use brew, but this solution should still work.

Comment: It's still works.

Answer (score 31):

Your best bet would be to use a [yarn version manager](https://yvm.js.org/).

### Install:

`curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tophat/yvm/master/scripts/install.sh | bash`

### Single usage:

`yvm exec <version> <command>`

### Or to switch your currently running yarn version

```
yvm use <version>
yarn --version
```

Comment: Getting `-bash: yvm: command not found` after running install and opening new terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: @TaylorAustin `source ~/.yvm/yvm.sh` does the job

Comment: ⚠️ Deprecation Notice (2022-02-20):
yvm has been deprecated in favour of corepack which is distributed by default with NodeJS v14, and is available in older versions by installing the corepack npm package globally.

Answer (score 26):

**UPDATE Dec 2021:**

Sadly brew switch is deprecated in [Homebrew 2.6.0](https://brew.sh/2020/12/01/homebrew-2.6.0/) (December 2020)

```sh
$ brew switch
Error: Unknown command: switch
```

TLDR, to switch version:

```sh
brew unlink yarn
brew link yarn@<new_version>
```

---

Old solution:

Assuming that you have the other version installed, you can run

```
brew switch yarn <old_version>
```

To list the versions you have installed:

```
brew list --versions yarn
```

Answer (score 11):

Easily install and switch between any number of yarn versions.

https://github.com/tophat/yvm

Answer (score 11):

Here's a way to do it with only `curl` and `bash`:

```
curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash -s -- --version 0.24.6  # or another version
```

This works whether you have yarn installed or not.

Answer (score 1):

For updating version on macOS use below command:

```
$ brew upgrade yarn
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the above answers don't seem to work anymore. Here is how I was able to install a different version in April 2021:

`brew unlink yarn@1.6.0` (If you already have a version installed)

`brew extract --version 1.22.4 yarn homebrew/cask`

`brew install yarn@1.22.4`

`yarn -v`