# yarn_install failed: yarn install v1.22.11

Tags: ios, yarnpkg, mediapipe

when I try to run mediapipe iOS demo by yarn, but I only get a "yarn_install failed: **yarn install v1.22.11**" response，Oddly enough, my Mac has yarn version 1.22.19, Have you ever been in a situation like this？

change the version config or I can user yarn v1.22.19 to make a successful.

Comment: Can you show the log in the console? It's not clear what the issue is

Comment: thanks a lot! I killed the issue by google! aha....

Comment: now, I'm trying to use Midiapipe to creat a iOS Application. Expect to succeed!

Comment: You'd better address the solution here so the others can refer to it. @

Comment: @Dream Bold  there is address:https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/hello_world_ios.html

Comment: I mean, how did you fix the last issue for `yarn install`? @

Comment: @DreamBold  open:https://sourceforge.net/projects/yarn.mirror/files/v1.22.11/ and download the file, then replace the local file.....

Comment: I added the solution as the answer to this question. It might help others!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to replace the yarn with the required version 1.22.11. The source could be downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/yarn.mirror/files/v1.22.11/)

More about the yarn version control [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448084/how-do-i-change-the-version-of-yarn-used)